# FFMPEG taking too long in offline encryption

Tags: encryption, ffmpeg

FFMPEG taking too much time to encrypting a video file.
I am running following command "ffmpeg -i "Sample.mp4" -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_key_info_file enc.keyinfo "sample.m3u8"".

To encrypt 708MB video file it takes around 22 minutes, Which is too much time so 
 **Is there any way to decress the time without changing the video quality?**

Comment: Do you mean to re-encode the video? If no, add `-c copy`.

Comment: @Mulvya I am doing encryption so when I add -c copy in a .mkv file it's show error. I don't work, it is fast but output video not working